# How to place input fields on top of a shaped div?

Tags: html, css

I have a Pentagon shaped div and I would like to have some input fields on it:

```css
/* creating the pentagon shape */

#pentagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 54px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-width: 50px 18px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: -85px;
  left: -18px;
  border-width: 0 45px 35px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent red;
}
.div{
  margin: 40px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <body>
    <div id="pentagon" class="div">
    <div style="position: absolute;"><input type="text" /></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
```

As you can see the shape of the Pentagon is created but if you place the input fields inside, it doesn't keep them on top.

Comment: This doesn't look particularly pentagon shaped in your example, could you double check it's appearing as intended? (Also, you seem to be creating the shape with borders in a way that will make it impossible to put things _in_ the shape, as the inside of the shape is not actually inside the element)

Comment: Given your example I think you have to put the inputs inside another containing div and then position this container wherever you need it on the pentagon, using `position: absolute`
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @DBS I just fixed the shape, it was my mistake when posting the code. Thanks! Now you can the pentagon shape but if you try placing input fields inside it wot work.

Comment: @Chaz I tried, check the updated code. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning using `absolute` as suggested in the comments will work if you use a negative `top` property.

To expand on why this wasn't working in the first place: You are creating the shape using an elements top/side borders, which means the element itself is actually hidden below the shape (As is any content you put inside it) Using absolute allows you to remove the child element from the regular document flow, and move it upwards, in the same way as the `:before` pseudo-element.

Basic fixed size example:

```css
/* creating the pentagon shape */

#pentagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 54px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-width: 50px 18px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: -85px;
  left: -18px;
  border-width: 0 45px 35px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent red;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.div{
  margin: 40px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <body>
    <div id="pentagon" class="div">
      <input />
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
```

Regarding your comment about different sized shapes, I've put together a version using CSS variables, you can edit the `--pwidth` variable in the `:root` to adjust the size while maintaining the correct shape:

```css
:root {
  --pwidth: 200px;
}

#pentagon {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--pwidth);
  border-width: calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.5555) calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.2222) 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red transparent;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  margin: calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.4444);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: calc(var(--pwidth) * -0.9444);
  left: calc(var(--pwidth) * -0.2222);
  border-width: 0 calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.5) calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.3888);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent red;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--pwidth) * -0.5);
  width: calc(var(--pwidth) * 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon">
  <input />
</div>
```

Comment: now we`re talking!! Thanks! How would you go about resizing (making the pentagon bigger) ?!

Comment: is it a feasible solution @DBS. Usually when i work on css , i try to avoid absolute

Comment: this would also work with position:relative if you need to position the inputs relative to the pentagon using negative `top` and `left` properties: https://jsfiddle.net/Chazlol/yh8jvs76/8/

Comment: @SandrinJoy `absolute` is perfectly valid when you need to break out of the regular document flow. That's generally not something you will want to do a lot, and overusing/abusing `absolute` is certainly a bad thing, but when you have a small contained element and the problem requires it, it can be a good solution.

Comment: @DBS Can you help with resizing this pentagon shape? I tried by increasing the width and other values but changes shape!

Comment: @dontdownvoteme In terms of making the shape bigger, there's quite a lot of changes/maths that need to be done. Off the top of my head, I think you would need to edit the: `#pentagon`s `width`, `border-width`. And the `#pentagon:before`s `top`, `left`, `border-width` properties. I'll see if I can figure it out and expand my answer.

Comment: @DBS thank you! However, I think I need to change the border radius as well to make those borders look rounded, but it seems impossible because this shape is made of two triangles so that cant be done. I guess I will have to go with a static image.

Answer (score 1):

Position input field using absolute position. Using absolute position we can change the position Relatively parent element's position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My jQuery</title>
    <style>
        /* creating the pentagon shape */
        #pentagon {
            position: relative;
            top: 41px;
            width: 81px;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            border-width: 50px 18px 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: red transparent;
        }
        #pentagon:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            top: -85px;
            left: -18px;
            border-width: 0 58px 35px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: transparent transparent red;
        }
        .div{
            margin: 40px
        }
        input {
            position: relative;
            top: -65px;
            left: -47px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<head>
<body>
<div id="pentagon" class="div">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <input type="text" ></div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this change may help you to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add  `z-index: -1;`  to your after pseudo element
so the `css` will look like this.

```
.pentagon:after {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 180px solid rgb(0, 66, 128);
  border-left: 180px solid transparent;
  border-right: 180px solid transparent;
  bottom: 180px;
  left: -90px;
  z-index: -1;  
}
```

Comment: nope, it doesnt work, it produces another shape of triangle!